# Is it possible to have multiple people work on the same Eclipse project at once? (Like Google Docs)

Tags: java, eclipse, server

If so, how could I pull this off? Can't find any direct guides for it through Google and have no knowledge of running webservers, so I'm not sure where to begin anyhow.

Comment: Use a source control system such as Git or SVN - there are Eclipse plugins for both of these and many others.

Comment: Was trying to setup realtime stuff, but I'll go with git if I can't figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

[DocShare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin) is a plugin that allows collaboration within Eclipse.

According to its wiki page it works through XMPP (Google Talk, Jabber, ...)

Comment: Thanks..Meanwhile I try to figure out what any of the stuff on that page means.